# Redefination of the function initialize leads to recursion in fabric.js

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I have my own class `PersonTextBox` inherited from the `Fabric Textbox`.

Also, I need to redefine function `initialize` for the Textbox, to change the behavior a little for objects with types `Textbox` and `PersonTextBox`.

I've implemented it in the next way:

```js
fabric.PersonTextBox = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Textbox, fabric.Observable, {  
  type: 'personTextBox'        
});

/**
 * Redefine function initialize.
 */
fabric.Textbox.prototype.initialize = function(text, options) {
  this.fillHtmlStyle(text);
  this.callSuper('initialize', text, options);
  this.setControlsVisibility(fabric.Textbox.getTextboxControlVisibility());
  this.ctx = this.objectCaching ? this._cacheContext : fabric.util.createCanvasElement().getContext('2d');
  // add width to this list of props that effect line wrapping.
  this._dimensionAffectingProps.push('width');
};

/**
 * Fill source text.
 * @text - plain text without html.
 */
fabric.Textbox.prototype.fillHtmlStyle = function(text) {
  this.htmlStyle = '<p>' + text + '</p>';
};

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
canvas.add(new fabric.PersonTextBox('My text'));
canvas.renderAll();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.7/fabric.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <canvas id="c" width="1000" height="1000"></canvas>
</body>
```

JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Eugene_Ilyin/p6ep1dfb/

as you can see, in the console appear an error:

```
fabric.js:1922 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at klass.callSuper (VM123 fabric.js:1922)
    at klass.fabric.Textbox.initialize ((index):55)
    at klass.callSuper (VM123 fabric.js:1925)
    at klass.fabric.Textbox.initialize ((index):55)
    at klass.callSuper (VM123 fabric.js:1925)
    at klass.fabric.Textbox.initialize ((index):55)
    at klass.callSuper (VM123 fabric.js:1925)
    at klass.fabric.Textbox.initialize ((index):55)
    at klass.callSuper (VM123 fabric.js:1925)
    at klass.fabric.Textbox.initialize ((index):55)
```

I found that in fabric v1.7.20 it works, but in v1.7.7 it doesn't work.
Why I do wrong and how can I correct this error?

Thanks in advance

Comment: That is working in >1.7.10, update fabricjs, may be it was a bug and that fixed already.

Comment: Updating can be a solution, but my system is pretty complex and it's already launched. An update can be a danger because it can break some custom logic. My current version is 1.7.9

Comment: There is no big difference , you can update it. In 1.7.10 the infinite loop bug is fixed.

Comment: So, I've checked a diff. Seems you're right, there are not so much changes. I will update fabric to 1.7.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a solution, I've updated my fabric.js library to version 1.7.10 and it helped.

Also, I found an issue describing this bug https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/pull/3844

But I've faced this problem again in another case.
After checking of the code, I found that when developer creates new class, he should use fabric.util.createClass. This function calls function addMethods. It allows calling functions by a chain of inheritance.

The conclusion is that overriding methods through prototype is an incorrect way for fabric.js. If you need to override some function, you should create your own class. Maybe overring of functions through prototype will work in some cases. But not in the case when you have "callSuper" inside of an overridden function.

P.S. I don't recommend to update on 1.7.10, this version has a bug with an SVG path.